# How to print array objects to a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing

I am a complete newbie in programming so be easy on me.

I want to print an array object into a table in HTML using getElementByID.

```
 <script>

       var ram = ["8GB", "3GB"];
       var storage = ["500GB" , "120GB"];

       document.getElementById("mac.r").innerHTML = ram[0];
       document.getElementById("mac.s").innerHTML = storage[0];

</script>
```

And I want to print it in a table

```
<table width="600" border="6" cellpadding="5px">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; Ram</td>
    <td>&nbsp; Storage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="mac.r"></td>
    <td id="mac.s"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use a macbook and google chrome.

Comment: Working fine. Whats the issue?

Comment: As @RahilWazir said, your code works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/jZjKR/1/

Comment: I think he meant that it only "prints" the first value and he would like all values - am I right @user3572468

Comment: I am using Google chrome to test and dreamweaver cc to write the code but it's not working @RahilWazir.

Comment: @TriniBoy How did you structure it in the HTML ?? where does the script tag go head or body ?? and do i need to use types or something ??

Comment: @user3572468: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must keep your script inline place it at the bottom of your page. See below, you can view the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jZjKR/2/)

Once the element exists that you need to populate, you then loop the the data you need and fill the related element with your data.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="600" border="6" cellpadding="5px">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp; Ram</td>
                <td>&nbsp; Storage</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="mac.r"></td>
                <td id="mac.s"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var ram = ["8GB", "3GB"];
                var storage = ["500GB", "120GB"];
                var macR = document.getElementById('mac.r');
                var macS = document.getElementById('mac.s');

                for(var i = 0; i < ram.length; i++){
                    if (macR !== null) macR.innerHTML = macR.innerHTML + ram[i] + "<br>";
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < ram.length; i++){
                    if (macS !== null) macS.innerHTML = macS.innerHTML + storage[i] + "<br>";
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to use the array's build-in "[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)" method:

```
var ram = ["8GB", "3GB"],
    storage = ["500GB" , "120GB"];

ram.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    document.getElementById("mac.r").innerHTML += element;
});

storage.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    document.getElementById("mac.s").innerHTML += element;
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/S3CY4/

Be aware though its mostly supported in modern browsers and it may not be the most performant approach.